# Celery doesn't return results

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

For some reason, whenever I create and run a new Task in Celery there is a problem with returning the results. The first task returns perfectly, but for all subsequent tasks, the result is always pending. I checked the Celery log, and it gets the correct result with no errors, but it just can't return it.

If it helps, I am running rabbitmq as my backend.

Comment: What version of Celery?  What do you use to store the results? (CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)

Comment: Version 2.2 and rabbitmq is my backend.

Comment: Wait. Sorry that doesn't make any sense. I haven't setup any database, or changed any of the config settings. Does that mean that it will default to AMQP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it turns out I just needed to explicitly specify a backend.

Adding:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
```

to my settings file seemed to fix everything.

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting the same issue even if I add 'amqp' backend.

Here is my celery config file:

```
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "guest"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "guest"
BROKER_VHOST = "/"

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 18000  # 5 hours.
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("test", )
```

My shell where first time get is successful and second time its hung. After sometime if I call the method again it works. This pattern keeps repeating.

```
>>> r = test.add.delay(4, 4)
>>> r.get()
8
>>> r = test.add.delay(4, 4)
>>> r.get()
^C <---------- it was hung here forever, I had to press ^C

>>> r = test.add.delay(4, 4)
>>> r.get()
8
```